# Jquery; validate if asp.net textbox has 19 character length and is in format

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a asp.net web application in which I have added bootstrap and jQuery. I want to check if the minimum and maximum length is 19 characters and has the format as below:
First 3 alphabets
Characters 4 till 15 are numbers
Character 16 is a period
character 17 to 19 contains the string zip

The field is defined as below:

```
<asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" ID="txtfilename" required="true" runat="server" placeholder="ABC1201901003.ZIP" />
```

I am trying to check in textbox change event:

```
$('#<%=txtfilename.ClientID%>').change(function (e) {
    var value = $(this).val();
});
```

How to check if the text has minimum and maximum characters and uses the format?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#<%=txtfilename.ClientID%>').change(function (e) {
    var value = $(this).val();
    if (value.length == 19) {
        let regex = /(([a-zA-Z]{3})+([0-9]{12})+(.zip))$/g; // regular expression to match the required string
        if ( value.match(regex) ) {
            // do stuff
        }
    }
});
```

Hope this helps. Don't forget to mark it as answer if this works.

Comment: Thanks. In the above code, can the last zip text be made case in-sensitive. I mean it should be fine for .zip / .ZIP / .Zip  like this